# Coldfusion Application variable magically becomes undefined?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, application.cfc

I'm trying to build an application that uses application.cfc instead of application.cfm. I'm running into a problem...I defined my dsn in my `onApplicationStart()` as `application.sacsds`. However, when I go to use in a cfc of mine, I get an error saying it is undefined.

```
<cfquery name = "getSecurity" datasource="#application.sacsds#">
```

Sorry for the simply question...I just couldn't figure this out.

Comment: Have you restarted the application since you defined the variable?

Comment: Hmm Good point...I'll try this. :P edit: yes still saying undefined when I invoke my cfc method.

Comment: @Bri - 1) Is "sacsds" really your *variable* name? 2) To be clear, you mean ran onApplicationStart() manually and nothing changed? 3) Dump the application  scope. What variables do you see?

Comment: I just did this (before you posted :P) and sacsds shows up in the application scope. Sorry for my incorrect lingo, I'm a rookie. Also, before my cfc is invoked, a custom login script is ran (not maintained by me) and then I use those variables as arguments for my cfc. The code in the cfc use to be just right after the custom login tag...and worked just fine.

Comment: You lost me ;) Is it still undefined? _Edit_ I see you may have found the problem.

Comment: @Leigh do you know a way to manually call application.cfc ? For instance, because this other application starts during the login, mine is ended...so I must restart my application.

Comment: @Bri - If your applications are overlapping somehow, restarting is just a band-aid. Please do not take offense, but the question is very ambiguous/scattered. You need to post more specific details about your application.cfm/cfc files, folder structure and how this login script is invoked. At this point, I do not know enough to even hazard a guess ;)

Comment: @Leigh thanks anyway. You answered my question pretty well and thanks for all your awesome help! I understand this is just a band-aid...but at the moment I probably don't have a choice, because I don't control that one and only login script/ custom coldfusion tag nor have access to place user credentials are stored. I think I may just ask for our own custom tag. I think this will give the best result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I dumped the scope within my CFC and found out it is completely wiping the application variables with other application variables. I think the issue lies within the login custom tag that is global to our domain. :( I'll have to have a word with someone.

Comment: Apparently, this is why our old code had two cfapplication tags. :\

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post searching for information on the same error.

My problem was a typo in the `Application.cfc`s file name.  It had two dots; so `Application..cfc`.  As such, ColdFusion was not executing the CFC; and the app code had no knowledge of the application scope.

Correctly naming the file addressed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar instance where I didn't know why my application variables were all of a sudden disappear. I found it was because another application AND my application on the web server didn't have  in the application.cfc and was confusing the application.cfc files. Thought I'd share!